# Inverse Matrix: Sum of the elements in each row

Tags: matrices, inverse

The question is:

Prove that If the sum of the elements of each row of a square matrix is k, then the sum of the elements in each row of the inverse matrix is 1/k ?

In the text book the answer is:

Let A be ${m\times m}$, non-singular, with the stated property. Let B be its imverse. Then for $n\leqslant m$,
$$
1 = \sum\limits_{r=1}^m \sigma_{nr} = \sum\limits_{r=1}^m\sum \limits_{s=1}^mb_{ns}a_{sr} = \sum\limits_{s=1}^m\sum \limits_{r=1}^mb_{ns}a_{sr}
 = k\sum\limits_{s=1}^m b_{ns}$$

(A is singular if K = 0).

I have trouble to understand this proof. Is there another way to prove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A$ be the invertible square matrix.

The product $A \pmatrix{1\\1\\\vdots\\1} $ gives a column matrix, with elements equal to sum of elements in a row of $A$.

$$\begin{align*}
 A \pmatrix{1\\1\\\vdots\\1} &=  \pmatrix{k\\k\\\vdots\\k} \\
A^{-1}A\pmatrix{1\\1\\\vdots\\1}  &= A^{-1} \pmatrix{k\\k\\\vdots\\k}\\
\pmatrix{1\\1\\\vdots\\1}  &= A^{-1} \pmatrix{k\\k\\\vdots\\k}\\
\pmatrix{1/k\\1/k\\\vdots\\1/k}  &= A^{-1} \pmatrix{1\\1\\\vdots\\1}\\
\end{align*}$$

i.e. each row of $A^{-1}$ sums to $\frac1k$, if $k\ne 0$.

Comment: Lovely Answer..

Answer (score 2):

Let $M$ be the matrix and $u$ be the vector with 1 for all its elements.
Then saying that the sum of all the elements in the rows of $M$ is $k$ is equivalent to saying that  $$Mu= ku$$
Now multiply that equation by $M^{-1}$ to the left:
$$u=kM^{-1}u$$ or $$\frac 1k u=M^{-1}u$$
Which means that the sum of the elements of the rows of $M^{-1}$ all equal $\frac 1k$.